# docker-compose up: FATAL: database "boilerplate," does not exist (Postgres Node)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose, node-postgres

I am trying to connect a node server to a postgres database with node-postgres (pg). My docker-compose.yaml is below:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./node-boilerplate
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: boilerplate,
      DB_HOST: db
  
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: boiler-db
    ports: 
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: boilerplate
```

When the node app tries to access a database called boilerplate that actually exists, it gives the error:

```
FATAL:  database "boilerplate," does not exist
```

However, when I connect to the postgres container (using `docker exec -it <postgres_container_ID> psql -U postgres`) and list databases with `\l`, it shows the database boilerplate listed.

What am I missing? How come the database shows up but the node server cannot find it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `DB_DATABASE: boilerplate, ` or `DB_DATABASE: boilerplate` without comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `docker-compose up` without comma:

```
  DB_DATABASE: boilerplate
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I did not see that and was struggling with it for hours. Thank you so much Thanh Nguyen Van!